# How to get program to write a new line in sequential access file instead of deleting it?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write to a sequential access file, but everytime I click the write button, the first listbox selection is deleted from the file and the new one is added, how do I fix this?

```
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'fills list box with parties
    partyListBox.Items.Add("Democrat")
    partyListBox.Items.Add("Republican")
    partyListBox.Items.Add("Independent")
End Sub

Private Sub writeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles writeButton.Click
    Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim party As String = partyListBox.SelectedItem.ToString
    Dim age As Integer

    Integer.TryParse(ageTextBox.Text, age)

    outFile = IO.File.CreateText("politicalparties.txt")
    'write to file
    outFile.WriteLine(party & ", " & age)
    'close file
    outFile.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your intention is for the text to be appended to the file?

Comment: @Alex Correct!, should I have the file created in the MainLoad sub, then just append it under the writebutton sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to append a line of text to the end of the file:

```
Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("politicalparties.txt")
    sw.WriteLine(party & ", " & age)
End Using
```

If the file does not yet exist, it will be created.